# git - show modified files, except for deleted (or renamed) files

Tags: git

I was using this git command to show modified files:

`git diff-index --name-only --cached HEAD`

It does show files modified, but I need it to make diff output ignore files that no longer exist (that they were either deleted or renamed).

For example let say I rename file `test.py` to `test2.py`.
Running command above would show:

`test.py
test2.py`

But output needs to be only: `test2.py`

P.S. I'm using this information to run checks on those files that were modified (edited or added). But I did not think about when files are renamed or removed. My used command will still show those files, but my checks will fail, because those files no longer exist and no checks should be run on them in a first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `--diff-filter=dr` to exclude delete files when doing the diff [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203)

*Edit: Thanks to [@RomainVALERI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057485/romainvaleri) for pointing out the `r` option for renamed

Comment: Thanks! I had a look for renamed, but for some reason must have just glanced over it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was testing with `--diff-filter=d`. But it seems it also excludes renamed files/directories. Cause I had test case were I renamed whole module and some files in it, but it filtered out those too. So is `r` option really needed? Or maybe it is interpreted by git to be deleted? Cause I added into staging both renamed from and to files?

Comment: @OliverRadini You're welcome. I was about to post near exactly the same answer but you've been faster ;-)